# What is the problem of <input type="file"/> .docx file type in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have an

```
<input type="file" accept="application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document">
```

like above to accept the `.doc` and `.docx` files. When I printed the file object to in Google Chrome console, `.docx` file type becomes empty. But in Firefox console, file type becomes not empty.

Here is my javascript function of input file change event;

```
var control = document.getElementById("upload-file");
control.addEventListener("change", function(event) {

    var files = control.files,
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        console.log("Filename: " + files[i].name);
        console.log("Type: " + files[i].type);
        console.log("Size: " + files[i].size + " bytes");
    }
}, false);
```

**Google Chrome Console Output**
[image]

**Firefox Console Output**
[image]

Comment: Google Chrome has some issues with the MIME types and I don't think they're going to update/fix those soon. Here's one of them: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=155455 . Also, you should not rely on detecting MIME types client side because that could be easily hi-jacked, especially on Windows. Bear in mind to do these kind of validations or checks on the server side.

Comment: Thank you @Nicolae Olariu. I have a similar validator too on the server for the mime-types.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the file extension ?

Using the same `accept` attribute:

```
<input type="file" accept=".doc, .docx, application/msword, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document">
```